# It appears a ?? when I put \label after \clearpage

Tags: cross-referencing

I met this problem when I put `\label{LastPage}` after `\include{chapter}`. I found that the `\ref{LastPage}` turned to `??` when I used `latexmk -pdf` to compile it. I tested the reason and knew that `\label` after `\clearpage` would turn `\ref` to `??`. Here is my code

```latex
% label after \clearpage
\documentclass{article}
% \usepackage{lastpage}
\begin{document}
    this is main file. \pageref{LastPage}
    \clearpage
    \label{LastPage}
\end{document}
```

I got the output
[image: image.png]

I want to know what led to this issue?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The last page of your document is effectively the one containing `this is main file. \pageref{LastPage}` as it is shipped out with a call to `\clearpage`. Since `\label` doesn't cause any printable content to be set, there are no other pages to be shipped out. And, since `\label`s are only "processed" during page shipout (in order to obtain the appropriate values of the page for `\pageref` - an asynchronous process to the content), your final `\label` is never processed, leaving `\pageref` to search for an unknown (page) reference `LastPage`.

The [`lastpage` package](//ctan.org/pkg/lastpage) does some work to circumvent a similar setup to yours, allow the following minimal example to work as expected, even though it matches your setup:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lastpage}

\begin{document}
this is main file. \pageref{LastPage}
\clearpage

\end{document}
```

Other options include the use of [`atveryend`](//ctan.org/pkg/atveryend) for placing `\label`s at the end of a document.

Answer (score 6):

I think this is probably because that no new page was actually created after the last `\clearpage`, since there's no content. Adding a `\null` or `\hbox{}` resolves this.

```
\documentclass{article}
% \usepackage{lastpage}
\begin{document}
    this is main file. \pageref{LastPage}
    \clearpage
    \null
    \label{LastPage}
\end{document}
```

Comment: But this creates a spurious page.